# Error with laravel: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fairly new to Laravel, but I'm trying to make a small API for my course. I've got this route `Route::get('films/search', 'App\Http\Controllers\FilmController@search');` which calls my custom function search which get as a parameter a Request. Here it is:

```
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $keyword = $request->input('keyword');
        $rating = $request->input('rating');
        $minLength = $request->input('minLength');
        $maxLength = $request->input('maxLength');

        if ($this->isParamExisting($keyword)) {
            return $this->getFromKeyword($keyword);
        } elseif ($this->isParamExisting($rating)) {
            return $this->getRatings($rating);
        } elseif ($this->isParamExisting($minLength)) {
            return $this->getMinLength($minLength);
        } elseif ($this->isParamExisting($maxLength)) {
            return $this->getMaxLength($maxLength);
        } else {
            return $this->getAllFilms();
        }
    }
```

At first it was working, but thenm I added joins in my models for other foreign keys and now it gives me `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object` and says it comes from my resource which is also used by my index method which works. I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

It may come from my route since when I put `@index` instead of my custom method it still gives me the error message. And I know my index works, because I'm using it on another route and there is no problem.

**Solution:**

The problem was coming from one of my other routes. I add one which used `films/{id}` and the system thought that search was used as an `{id}`. I changed my route for `Route::get('films/search/param', 'App\Http\Controllers\FilmController@search');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The problem was coming from one of my other routes. I add one which used films/{id} and the system thought that search was used as an {id}. I changed my route for Route::get('films/search/param', 'App\Http\Controllers\FilmController@search');

Answer (score 0):

the error because you're trying access an id which doesn't exist in your database.
can you show me the code In your model ! and the functions that you call it In search method.

Comment: I actually found the error but thanks. I'm going to edit my question and close it now !